# DeclareDocumentEnvironment: missing control sequence inserted -- \inaccessible

Tags: environments, xparse, key-value

I'm setting up a skeleton CV package for a friend for him to customize, and I'd like to make it as user-friendly as possible.  To effect this, I'm using `keyval` and `xparse`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{setup.sty}
  \RequirePackage{xparse}
  \RequirePackage{keyval}
  \define@key{position}{title}  {\def{\position@title}  {#1}}
  \define@key{position}{date}   {\def{\position@date}   {#1}}
  \define@key{position}{company}{\def{\position@company}{#1}}
  \define@key{position}{place}  {\def{\position@place}  {#1}}
  \DeclareDocumentEnvironment{position}{m}{%
    \begingroup
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\setkeys{position}{title={},date={},company={},place={}}}
    {\setkeys{position}{title={},date={},company={},place={},#1}}

    \begin{description}
    \item[Title]   \position@title
    \item[Date]    \position@date
    \item[Company] \position@company
    \item[Place]   \position@place
    \end{description}
    \endgroup
  }{}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setup}

\begin{document}
\begin{position}{title=hello}
  Hey
\end{position}
\end{document}
```

This, to me, seems like a fairly standard use of `xparse` and `keyval`, so I'm likely to be missing something rather plain and Read-The-Fine-Manual-y, but I can't find any errors and the error message is still cryptic to me -- I've never gotten it before.  Here is the error message in all of its glory:

> ```
> ERROR: Missing control sequence inserted.
>
> --- TeX said ---
> <inserted text> 
>                 \inaccessible 
> l.55 \begin{position}{title=hello}
>
> --- HELP ---
> This is probably caused by a \newcommand, \renewcommand, \newlength,
> or \newsavebox command whose first argument is not a command name.
> ```

What is going on here, and how can I make TeX happy again?

By the way, if anyone would care to give the equivalent `xkeyval` solution in their answer, I'm always happy to learn something new :-).

---

I've been spoiled a little by AUCTeX; there are more errors available in the log file that are perhaps more helpful:

```
... style imports ...
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.56 \begin{position}{title=hello}

! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.56 \begin{position}{title=hello}

! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.56 \begin{position}{title=hello}

! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.56 \begin{position}{title=hello}

! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.56 \begin{position}{title=hello}

! Undefined control sequence.
\environment position code ...le] \position@title 
                                                  \item [Date] \position@dat...
l.56 \begin{position}{title=hello}

! Undefined control sequence.
\environment position code ...ate] \position@date 
                                                  \item [Company] \position@...
l.56 \begin{position}{title=hello}

! Undefined control sequence.
\environment position code ...] \position@company 
                                                  \item [Place] \position@pl...
l.56 \begin{position}{title=hello}

! Undefined control sequence.
\environment position code ...ce] \position@place 
                                                  \end {description} \endgroup l.56 \begin{position}{title=hello}
... see transcript file for additional information, etc. etc. ...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\def` is a primitive command that has the syntax

```
\def<control sequence><parameter text>{<replacement text>}
```

where `<control sequence>` means either a control sequence name starting with `\` or an active character. Any other token after `\def` is illegal and TeX tries to recover by inserting a special control sequence called `\inaccessible`. The error message is quite clear:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
                \inaccessible
<to be read again>
                   {
l.18 \def{
          \position@title}  {hi}
```

You can see where TeX has stopped: it found `{` after `\def`; the offending `{` token has been put back in the input stream and will be read again as if it had not yet been read. Between `\def` and `{` TeX has inserted `\inaccessible` that you can still remove by typing `1` and then `i\foo` to insert the control sequence name you probably forgot to add (at least this is what TeX is thinking).

If you're not confident with low level TeX commands, you can still stick with LaTeX's model. Just initialize `\position@title` before the `\define@key` command:

```
\newcommand{\position@title}{}
\define@key{position}{title}{\renewcommand{\position@title}{#1}}
```

Braces around the first argument to `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` are allowed (the LaTeX manual always uses them) but not required.

Actually, initializing the containers avoids the clumsy code in the setting of the keys you do later on.

Let's see your code:

```
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{position}{m}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
  {\setkeys{position}{title={},date={},company={},place={}}}
  {\setkeys{position}{title={},date={},company={},place={},#1}}

  \begin{description}
  \item[Title]   \position@title
  \item[Date]    \position@date
  \item[Company] \position@company
  \item[Place]   \position@place
  \end{description}
  \endgroup
}{}
```

There is no need to set the keys with empty values, because the default value is empty anyway, if you have initialized them.

Another thing to note is that the true branch of `\IfNoValueTF` will *never* be followed: that function is for optional argument, not for mandatory ones. There is no need for `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` either, because the keys will be set in the group opened by `\begin{position}`.

Therefore a more efficient code would be

```
\newcommand{\position@title}  {}
\newcommand{\position@date}   {}
\newcommand{\position@company}{}
\newcommand{\position@place}  {}
\define@key{position}{title}  {\renewcommand{\position@title}  {#1}}
\define@key{position}{date}   {\renewcommand{\position@date}   {#1}}
\define@key{position}{company}{\renewcommand{\position@company}{#1}}
\define@key{position}{place}  {\renewcommand{\position@place}  {#1}}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{position}{m}
  {%
   \setkeys{position}{#1}
   \begin{description}
   \item[Title]   \position@title
   \item[Date]    \position@date
   \item[Company] \position@company
   \item[Place]   \position@place
   \end{description}
  }{}
```

I suggest a slightly different path: you can use `l3keys`.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { sean/position }
 {
  title   .tl_set:N = \l_sean_position_title_tl,
  date    .tl_set:N = \l_sean_position_date_tl,
  company .tl_set:N = \l_sean_position_company_tl,
  place   .tl_set:N = \l_sean_position_place_tl,
 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{position}{m}
 {
  \begin{description}
  \keys_set:nn { sean/position } { #1 }
  \item[Title]   \l_sean_position_title_tl
  \item[Date]    \l_sean_position_date_tl
  \item[Company] \l_sean_position_company_tl
  \item[Place]   \l_sean_position_place_tl
  \end{description}
 }{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The `\keys_define:nn` and `\keys_set:nn` functions are already available with `\usepackage{xparse}`.

Comment: I wonder if/when L3 syntax will stop looking so foreign to me... what's with the `:nn` after `\keys_(define|set)`?

Comment: For the equally curious: `texdoc expl3`

Comment: @SeanAllred `:nn` means that the function (command, if you prefer) wants two braced arguments. It's a great feature for the programmer.

Comment: @SeanAllred I'd recommend `texdoc interface3` over `expl3`.

Answer (score 4):

From the [TeX Book](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbook) (**Chapter 20 Definitions (also called Macros)**, p 203):

> ... let's look at the precise rules that govern TeX macros. Definitions have the general form
>
> ```
> \def<control sequence><parameter text>{<replacement text>}
> ```
>
> where the `<parameter text>` contains no `braces`, and where all occurrences
>   of `{` and `}` in the `<replacement text>` are properly nested. Furthermore
>   the `#` symbol has a special significance: In the `<parameter text>`, the
>   first appearance of `#` must be followed by `1`, the next by `2`, and
>   so on; up to nine `#`'s are allowed. In the `<replacement text>` each `#`
>   must be followed by a digit that appeared after `#` in the `<parameter text>`,
>   or else the `#` should be followed by another `#`. The latter case stands
>   for a single `#` token when the macro is expanded; the former case stands
>   for insertion of the corresponding argument.

It is clear from this that `<control sequence>` should not be braced.

---

Regarding your use of [`keyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval), you could also use the [`xkeyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval)'s "command keys" via `\define@cmdkey`. From the [`xkeyval` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xkeyval/doc/xkeyval.pdf) (section **3.2 Command keys**, p 5):

> The following two lines also implement a key with the same key macro:
>
> ```
> \define@cmdkey{fam}[my@]{key}[none]{value: \my@key}% xkeyval syntax
> \define@key{fam}{key}[none]{\def\mykey{#1}value: \my@key}% keyval syntax
> ```

Comment: I truly wish in this case that I could accept both!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

This actually has *nothing* to do with {xparse}, {keyval}, or {environments} at all.  All I needed to do was to remove the braces from the `\def`.

I was playing around with potential workarounds/solutions from Joseph Wright's [TUGBoat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94wright-keyval.pdf) on `keyval` interfaces, and decided to try out page 111's suggestion of defining the container macro (e.g. `position@title`) before the actual keys are made.  This popped up a different error, but one that was definitely more pinned down:

```
ERROR: Missing control sequence inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.18 \def{
          \position@title}  {hi}
--- HELP ---
This is probably caused by a \newcommand, \renewcommand, \newlength,
or \newsavebox command whose first argument is not a command name.
```

From here, it was relatively obvious that the `{` and `}` characters were the source of the problem, although *I still don't know why*.  **Any additional resources to that end would be most appreciated.**